# Groovy null check not working on a property in the list

Tags: groovy, truthiness

POJO:

```
  class Item{
    String prop1
    String prop2
    }
```

My Data:

`List<Item> items = new ArrayList(new Item(prop1: 'something'), new Item(prop1: 'something'))`

Then I try:

```
 if(items?.prop2){
    //I thought prop 2 is present
    }
```

even though the prop2 is null on both items in the items list, above code returns me true and goes inside if statement.

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `items?.prop2` returns `[null, null]`. And since a non-empty list evaluates to true...

You should be able to identify what you need from the following example:

```
class Item {
    String prop1
    String prop2
}

List<Item> items = [new Item(prop1: 'something'), new Item(prop1: 'something')]

assert items?.prop2 == [null, null]
assert [null, null] // A non-empty list evaluates to true
assert !items?.prop2.every() // This may be what you're looking for
assert !items?.prop2.any() // Or Maybe, it's this

if(items?.prop2.every()) {
    // Do something if all prop2's are not null
    println 'hello'
}

if(items?.prop2.any()) {
    // Do something if any of the prop2's are not null
    println 'world'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` operator that spreads the list returns list of the same size with the value of the property you look for (in this case, list of 2 nulls). Not empty lists evaluate to true.